# Obtain a file that contains the information of my model on sirius OBEO

Tags: model, entity, code-generation, eclipse-sirius

I created my graphic model with Sirius using my own grammar everything is perfect, Node in the graph the relationships between Node etc.

Now I want to generate a file containing all the information of the titles of my Node and the relations between Node ect.

Someone knows what is called this document and how to generate it, I think it is an .ENTITY file but if someone has more information please share it with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your model right here :

MyProjectSirius/org.xtext.UnivTlmcen.pfe/instances.pfe

pfe = extention of your project.